# Monitoring AWS Api Gateway Using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want to monitoring "How many api call on AWS API GATEWAY".

I can monitoring API call using "Usage Plans" on AWS console.
Usage Plans => Select Plans => API Keys => Select API Key => Click Usage.

How implement it using node.js?

Answer (score 1):

From [Amazon API Gateway Dimensions and Metrics - Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html):

> `Count`: The total number API requests in a given period.

So, you can obtain this information directly out of **Amazon CloudWatch**.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This is the code for get API call count.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var apigateway = new AWS.APIGateway({
  apigateway: '2015-07-09',
  accessKeyId: '',
  secretAccessKey: '',
  region: '',
});

var params = {
  endDate: '', /* required */
  startDate: '', /* required */
  usagePlanId: '', /* required */
  keyId: '',
};
apigateway.getUsage(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Source : [AWSJavaScriptSDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#getUsagePlan-property)